# Is there a way to plot a graph with the count of each person gender on a dataset grouped by time?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph that shows the amount of people grouped by gender, and show how frequently they shop in local store using a dataset that contains

```
gender  object

size    int64

price   float64
```

and a 'date' column `'M%D%Y'` that is the index.

Here what a `dataframe.head()` looks like:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBTes.png)

The closest I got from what I want is this:

```py
df2018.groupby(['date'])['gender'].count().plot()
```

But it shows the count of both occorrencies.

I'm trying to get something like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVX3q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more like a `crosstab` and `plot` problem

```
pd.crosstab(df2018['date'], df2018['gender']).plot()
```

Comment: I just had to remove the date index to it work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Group by the gender and date not just the date:

```
df2018.groupby(['date', 'gender']).count().plot()
```

Comment: I've tried this one but I get a a weird graph instead.
[Image](http://prntscr.com/o1n05q)